# TableView Crashes on reloadData - 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In my `tableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I use a custom cell for the first row and a regular `UITableViewCell` for the other rows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

    if (indexPath.section == 0){
        CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.titleLabel.text = @"Custom cell";

        if (isLightTheme){
           cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
        else{
           cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }

        return cell;
    }
    else{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Other cells";

        if (isLightTheme){
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
        else{
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }

        return cell;

    }
```

}

I then call a method that changes isLightTheme and reloads data:

```
-(void)changeTheme{

   isLightTheme = false;
   [self.myTable reloadData];
}
```

... but my app crashes on this line:

```
    cell.titleLabel.text = @"Custom cell";
```

with the error:

> '-[UITableViewCell titleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I don't understand what's going on.. the table loads perfectly fine (`isLightTheme` is first set to `true`) when the `ViewController` first loads, but when I change `isLightTheme` and `reloadData` it crashes.  Could anybody help me out?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reuse identifier is the same for both of your cells. The custom and the default. Use unique values for each.

Comment: Glad to help! UITableViews can be frustrating but you'll come to LOVE them shortly. ;-)